# Live streaming is not working using zegocloud api

Tags: flutter, dart, live-streaming, zegocloud

I am trying to implement live streaming using zegocloud api. but I am getting this error in the terminal -

```
E/flutter (24101): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exceptio
n: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getVersion on channel plugins.zego.im/zego_express_engine)
E/flutter (24101): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #1      ZegoExpressImpl.getVersion (package:zego_express_engine/src/impl/zego_express_impl.dart:219:12)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #2      ZegoExpressEngine.getVersion (package:zego_express_engine/src/zego_express_api.dart:146:12)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #3      ZegoUIKitCore.getZegoUIKitVersion (package:zego_uikit/src/services/internal/core/core.dart:53:28)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101):
I/PLogger (24101): {call}  {overlay machine}  {init}  {08/11/2023 16:45:44}  {INFO}     
I/PLogger (24101): {live streaming}  {core manager}  {init plugin and managers}  {08/11/2023 16:45:44}  {INFO}
I/PLogger (24101): {live streaming}  {connect manager}  {init}  {08/11/2023 16:45:44}  {INFO}
I/PLogger (24101): {live streaming}  {host manager}  {set connect manager}  {08/11/2023 16:45:44}  {INFO}
E/flutter (24101): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exceptio
n: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method setEngineConfig on channel plugins.zego.im/zego_express_engine)
E/flutter (24101): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:308:7)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #1      ZegoExpressImpl.setEngineConfig (package:zego_express_engine/src/impl/zego_express_impl.dart:148:12)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #2      ZegoExpressEngine.setEngineConfig (package:zego_express_engine/src/zego_express_api.dart:48:12)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #3      ZegoUIKitCore.setAdvanceConfigs (package:zego_uikit/src/services/internal/core/core.dart:176:5)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #4      ZegoUIKit.setAdvanceConfigs (package:zego_uikit/src/services/uikit_service.dart:96:5)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101): #5      _ZegoUIKitPrebuiltLiveStreamingState.initContext.<anonymous c
losure> (package:zego_uikit_prebuilt_live_streaming/src/components/live_streaming.dart:304:7)
E/flutter (24101): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (24101):.
```

Help me fix this error. also the Audio and video is not working. it is not showing anything. someone help me fix the issue.

I am trying to make a live streaming app using zegocloud uikit but it is giving me errors in the terminal and the video and audio is also not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException: No implementation found for method xx on channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70167194/unhandled-exception-missingpluginexception-no-implementation-found-for-method)